# Girl is a descendant of the Brothers Grimm. Has powers that relate to their stories and the surname "Grimes"

Tags: story-identification, novel

There's a story I read a few years ago that really got me interested. From what I can remember, it's about a girl who's a descendant of the Brothers Grimm, and her mother and her have to move constantly because they're being followed. The protagonist's fake last name is 'Grimes', and she's constantly bullied over that. Lastly, she basically has powers involving the stories that the Brother's Grimm wrote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [UnEnchanted](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13402447-unenchanted) by Chanda Hahn.

> Mina Grime is unlucky, unpopular and uncoordinated, that is until she
>   saves her crush's life on a field trip, changing her High School
>   status from loser to hero overnight. But with her newfound fame brings
>   misfortune as an old family curse come to light.
>
> For Mina is descended from the Brothers Grimm and has inherited all of
>   their unfinished fairy tale business. Which includes trying to outwit
>   a powerful Story from making her its next fairytale victim.
>
> To break the fairy tale curse on her family and stop these deadly
>   events, Mina must finish the tales until the very Grimm end.

[image]

Comment: Yup! That's the one! Now I can finally get started with the rest of the series! Thank you for responding so quickly as well.

Comment: [Glad you found what you were looking for.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)